# Warning on my WordPress site

Tags: warnings

Domain showing an alert message of " Deceptive site ahead ". 
How can I resolve this issue, please help.
I have attached the screenshot showing error.

[image]

Comment: what is the Site URL?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6350487?hl=en . The "Fixing the problem" section might be usefull for you. If you find a solution on there, make sure you awnser you own question here!

Comment: I have done it. I just remove the WordPress site and database from my c panel then I added my domain to the web master tool and it showing me there was a malicious content. I have then submitted for a review after few hours I received email from web master that it is secured now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a single reason why you see this type of warning. A nulled theme or plugin is a happy ground for malware, virus rootkits, backdoors and more.

As this is true for most sites **Major Browser** and **Search Engines** are taking steps to protect the users. As such warnings exist for the protection of users you should also have ways to be able to tell the reason that trick this warning.

### Finding the Reason

> An excellent source will be [Google Search Console](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) (former Google
>   webmaster).

There there is a tab that shows this activity and telling next steps to resolve it.

> This warning may be up a time after you resolve the issues because it
>   should be recrawled and verified, a process that requires time and
>   manual action.

Also removing only the files didn't mean you are safe. Backdoors exist also in the **Database**.

Comment: Thanks @Drupalizeme. You have not explained well but I have got the point from your answer to go through the web master tool and I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following things:

1. Your wordpress versions should be upto date.
2. You are not using any cracked / nulled theme plugins there might be some malicous code into it.
3. Still you are facing issue you may install this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/)

PLease check it and let me know if you need any further help

Comment: I used cracked / nulled theme on my domain after few days I got this issue, then I remove the WordPress all folders/sub folders.But still I am facing this problem @Pratik

Comment: Are you still using the same theme?

Comment: No, I have deleted the theme two weeks before but still domain showing me error.

Comment: This advice is horribly generic. As someone who has cleaned up tons of WordPress infections I assure you that this advice *won’t* solve any issue. It’s like telling someone who has just been stabbed to get their medical insurance ready, get plenty of rest and drink some water.

Comment: @JakeGould The answer was posted before any comments on the post or anymore data so Please check the timespan for the same before posting any comments here.

Comment: In that case you need to add site listing through your webmaster tools.

Comment: @Pratikbhatt And even with more info and data this answer is utterly useless to solve this issue. The site is hacked. Updating WordPress and plugins won’t clean it up. Case closed.

Comment: So what should I do guys @Pratikbhatt,JakeGould ?

Comment: @JakeGould Can you please help me out regarding this issue before site is going to be hacked?

Comment: @HeroWeb512 Scan with all in one security wordpress and if you do not get any errors you need to send a request for the same to google using your webmaster tools

Comment: @HeroWeb512 Your site is already hacked and there is no easy solution. Sorry.

Comment: But still I have all the access of my domain and server @JakeGould.Can I not resolved it either changing the IP address of the server or domain?

Comment: I think it's not hacked, it just giving me a warning message @JakeGould and I have also removed the WordPress and database of the domain from my c panel.

Comment: @Pratikbhatt I have removed WordPress and database of the domain from my c panel because of the warning message. Should I installed it again, I have a cracked theme.

Comment: @HeroWeb512 If it’s not hacked then why are services that detecting malware picking up on this? They would only report your site as “Deceptive” if you are actually hacked.

Comment: I am feeling happy that I have done it @JakeGould and Pratikbhatt